# Bison throwing syntax error but I can't see my error

Tags: c, syntax-error, bison, flex-lexer

I wrote simple program that hopefully is infix calculator that outputs postfix representation and it's value. I dont know why but when I run it and pass to it simple data I get syntax error. Here is what I pass, what I get back along with src files.

Execution:

```
2+2+2
2 2 + 
4
syntax error
```

Bison file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

extern int yylex();
extern int yyparse();

void yyerror(const char *msg);
%}

%union {
    int ival;
}

%token <ival> NUM
%type <ival> N M P A

%%

S : A               {printf("\n%d\n", $1);}
    ;

A   : P '-' P       {printf("- "); $$ = (int)($1 - $3);}
    | P '+' P       {printf("+ "); $$ = (int)($1 + $3);}
    | P             {$$ = $1;}
    ;

P   : M '/' M       {printf("/ "); $$ = (int)($1 / $3);}
    | M '*' M       {printf("* "); $$ = (int)($1 * $3);}
    | M '%' M       {printf("% "); $$ = (int)($1 % $3);}
    | M             {$$ = $1;}
    ;

M   : N '^' N       {printf("^ "); $$ = (int)pow($1, $3);}
    | N             {$$ = $1;}
    ;

N   : '(' A ')'     {$$ = $2;}
    | '-' N         {printf("-%d ", $2); (int)($$ = -$2);}
    | NUM           {printf("%d ", $1); (int)($$ = $1);}
    ;

%%

void main() {
    yyparse();
    return;
}

void yyerror(const char *msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
}
```

Flex file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bison.tab.h"
%}

%%

#.*\n
"\\"\n
[0-9]+      {
                yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); 
                return NUM;
            }

[-+*/^%()]  {
                return yytext[0];
            }
[ \t\n]

%%
```

Can you see my mistake? Maby I just didn't read Bison documentation good enough. It's pretty hard to find any tutorials on it.

Comment: @GeorgiHristozov Lex and flex are different tools. The correct tag for flex, the lexical analyzer, is flex-lexer.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: I think the problem is that you don't have the recursion in your grammar to allow chaining operations. It looks like `(2+2)+2` would work with your grammar, though.

Comment: @FredLarson: Ah — I missed that the first box of code scrolled; my bad.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same thing initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found solution but I dont know why it worked If someone want to clarify I would appreciate I'm not good at formal languages. What I changed is:

```
P   : M '/' M       {printf("/ "); $$ = (int)($1 / $3);}
    | M '*' M       {printf("* "); $$ = (int)($1 * $3);}
    | M '%' M       {printf("% "); $$ = (int)($1 % $3);}
    | M             {$$ = $1;}
    ;
```

Changed into:

```
P   : P '/' M       {printf("/ "); $$ = (int)($1 / $3);}
    | P '*' M       {printf("* "); $$ = (int)($1 * $3);}
    | P '%' M       {printf("% "); $$ = (int)($1 % $3);}
    | M             {$$ = $1;}
    ;
```

And did accordingly to every nonterminal.

Comment: If you have `M '/' M`, then you can have one `/` with an exponentiation, (possibly negated) number or parentheses on each side, right? But what you can't have on either side is another division (or multiplication or modulo) because `M` doesn't match that. If you change one of the `M`s to `P`, you can now have another division (or ...) on that side. So `1 / 2 / 3` is now a division with `1 / 2` on the left side (matching the `P`) and `3` on the right side (matching the `M`).

Comment: If you used `M '/' P` instead, it would be 1 on the left side and `2 / 3` on the right (which is wrong because division is supposed to be left-associative). And if you used `P '/' P`, it would be ambiguous because either version could be derived (leading to conflicts unless you add associativity declarations). So that's why `P '/' M` is correct.